# Drop multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to drop multiple columns (column 2 and 70 in my data set, indexed as 1 and 69 respectively) by index number in a pandas data frame with the following code:

```py
df.drop([df.columns[[1, 69]]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

And in my code the `[1, 69]` is highlighted and says:

```
Expected type 'Integral', got 'list[int]' instead
```

The following code does what I want in two lines of repetitive code (first dropping col index 69, then 1, and order does matter because dropping earlier columns changes the index of later columns).

```py
df.drop([df.columns[69]], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop([df.columns[1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to do this in one line similar to the first code snippet above?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You don't need to wrap it in a list with `[..]`, just provide the subselection of the columns index:

```
df.drop(df.columns[[1, 69]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

as the index object is already regarded as list-like.

Comment: Note df.columns[1:69] can be used for columns 2-70.

Answer (score 22):

Try this

`df.drop(df.iloc[:, 1:69], inplace=True, axis=1)`

This works for me

Comment: For newer users, I recommend this answer as it will force you to work with positional indexing `df.iloc` which you will see appear in a lot of other questions looking to do something on a column or row in a given position (first, last, nth, between ith and jth, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

A readable version is to pass the `columns=` argument.

```py
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns[[1, 69]])
```

Putting `df.columns[[1, 69]]` inside a list (as in OP) becomes useful if we want to drop columns both by integer position and name(s) (simply need to unpack the array with `*`). For example, the following code drops the 2nd and the 70th columns along with another column named `Some_Col`.

```py
df = df.drop(columns=[*df.columns[[1, 69]], 'Some_Col'])
```

Another way to drop columns is via the `iloc` indexer. For example, to drop the 2nd and 70th columns:

```py
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[:1, 2:69, 70:df.shape[1]]]
# or
df = df.iloc[:, ~np.isin(np.arange(df.shape[1]), [1,69])]
```