# Issue with dropping columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to read in a data set and dropping the first two columns of the data set, but it seems like it is dropping the wrong column of information.  I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347412/drop-multiple-columns-pandas) thread, but their suggestion is not giving the expected answer.  My data set starts with 6 columns, and I need to remove the first two.  Elsewhere in threads it has the option of dropping columns with labels, but I would prefer not to name columns only to drop them if I can do it in one step.

```
df= pd.read_excel('Data.xls', header=17,footer=246)
df.drop(df.columns[[0,1]], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

But it is dropping columns 4 and 5 instead of the first two.  Is there something with the drop function that I'm just completely missing?

Comment: Print out `df.columns` and make sure it looks like what you were expecting.  Maybe the order got changed somewhere?

Comment: OK, that seems to be the issue here.  When I do that, I get this output:

Index(['Petajoules', 'Gigajoules', '%'], dtype='object')

Petajoules is the third column when I visually look at the data set.  The first two columns are not included in this.  How would I drop those two columns if they aren't in df.columns?

Comment: The first two columns might be in the index (multi-index).  try `df.reset_index()` -- that converts index columns into regular columns.

Comment: Thanks, it was the index.  However, now that leads to a different problem.  When I try using df.reset_index(), I get an error ("cannot do an non-empty take from an empty axes").

Even if I got solved that error, isn't reset_index() a destructive process?  The third column of the multilevel index is what I need to reset it to.  However, when I try using df.set_index, it wouldn't let me reset it to the appropriate column because it is currently an index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a multilevel index, so drop columns [0, 1] will start counting on non-index columns.

If you know the position of the columns, why not try selecting it directly, such as:

```
df = df.iloc[:, 3:]
```